# SharePoint Online List View- Filter by a date column and Start and End of Month dates

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, calculated-column

I would like to create a list view that filters out items with 'Date Joined' in the the current month/year.

I have created two calculated columns - `StartOfMonth` and `EndOfMonth`

`StartOfMonth = DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),1)`

`EndOfMonth= DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created)+1,1)-1`

I am not able to save the view with the filters. Can anyone advise what the issue is?

[image]

Comment: What is your calculated column Return data type?

Comment: @Pradip R. Date and Time

Comment: Check if this solution works in your case http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/11/howto-filter-items-current-calendar-month-view-sharepoint/

Comment: @Pradip R. Yes, it works. Thank you!

Comment: I have provided a solution to this issue in the form of an answer. I kindly request that you mark it as the accepted answer so that others can benefit from this solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

In summary from the comment,

Your two calculated formulas as follows:

`StartOfMonth = DATE(YEAR([DateJoined]), MONTH([DateJoined]), 1)`

`EndOfMonth = DATE(YEAR([DateJoined]), MONTH([DateJoined]) + 1, 1) - 1`

Next, create a new view, such as "Joinee This Month," and set up the following filter:

```
StartOfMonth is less than or equal to [Today]

AND

EndofMonth is greater than or equal to [Today]
```

For more detailed instructions, you can refer to the original article at this link: http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/11/howto-filter-items-current-calendar-month-view-sharepoint/